# How do I install QuickTime from a .pkg?

Tags: install, quicktime

I'm on a laptop running OS X 10.3.9 (Panther) and I've downloaded "QuickTime 7.5 for Panther updater" -- and for the life of me I can't figure out how to install it.

The file mounts as a disk image. When I doubleclick it I see a `QuickTime75_Panther.pkg` file which opens when I double click. Inside I see a lot more files but nothing that lets me install. Help?

Answer (score 4):

`.pkg` files are so called [packages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_%28Mac_OS_X%29), which can be installed by [`Installer.app`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Installer_%28Mac_OS_X%29), so try right-clicking the `.pkg` file and hit `Open with -> Installer`

Comment: However by default .pkg files open with Installer so you have changed something on your machine.

Comment: @Mark you're right. Should have mentioned that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the .pkg file using the following command on Terminal.app(assuming your .pkg file is in Downloads directory).

```
sudo installer -pkg ~/Downloads/QuickTime75_Panther.pkg /Applications/
```

The above command will install QT on the Applications directory.